# Is it possible to use Mongo Shell style queries with Spark's Cosmos DB Connector?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, azure-cosmosdb

I'm using the Cosmos DB Connector for Spark. Is it possible to use Mongo Shell "JSON-style" queries with the Cosmos DB connector instead of SQL queries?

I tried using the MongoDB Connector instead to achieve the same functionality but have run into some annoying bugs with memory limits using the Mongo Connector. So I've abandoned that approach.

This is the way I'd prefer to query:

```js
val results = db.cars.find(
    {
        "car.actor.account.name": "Bill"
    }
)
```

This is the way the cosmos connector allows:

```scala
val readConfig: Config = Config(Map(
  "Endpoint" -> config.getString("endpoint"),
  "Masterkey" -> config.getString("masterkey"),
  "Database" -> config.getString("database"),
  "Collection" -> "cars",
  "preferredRegions" -> "South Central US",
  "schema_samplesize" -> "100",
  "query_custom" -> "SELECT * FROM root WHERE root['$v']['car']['$v']['actor']['$v']['account']['$v']['name']['$v'] = 'Bill'"
))

val results = spark.sqlContext.read.cosmosDB(readConfig)
```

Obviously the SQL-oriented approach doesn't lend itself well to the deeply nested data structures I'm getting from Cosmos DB. It's quite a bit more verbose, too; requiring each nested dictionary to be referenced with "['$v']" for reasons I'm unclear on. I'd much prefer to be able to use the Mongo-style syntax.

Comment: You can have a look at http://reactivemongo.org/releases/0.1x/documentation/tutorial/azure-cosmos.html

Comment: Will that work with apache spark?

Comment: It explains how to connect, you should be able to adapt whatever is the driver.

Answer (score 0):

The Cosmos DB Connector for Spark mentioned in this link is for Cosmos DB SQL API, so you only can query it in SQL-oriented

```
// Import Necessary Libraries
import com.microsoft.azure.cosmosdb.spark.schema._
import com.microsoft.azure.cosmosdb.spark._
import com.microsoft.azure.cosmosdb.spark.config.Config

// Read Configuration
val readConfig = Config(Map(
  "Endpoint" -> "https://doctorwho.documents.azure.com:443/",
  "Masterkey" -> "YOUR-KEY-HERE",
  "Database" -> "DepartureDelays",
  "Collection" -> "flights_pcoll",
  "query_custom" -> "SELECT c.date, c.delay, c.distance, c.origin, c.destination FROM c WHERE c.origin = 'SEA'" // Optional
))

// Connect via azure-cosmosdb-spark to create Spark DataFrame
val flights = spark.read.cosmosDB(readConfig)
flights.count()
```

But if your cosmos db is mongo api,you could follow the statements in above link:

[image]

Please refer to this guide:https://docs.mongodb.com/spark-connector/master/python/read-from-mongodb/